# VBA to auto increment row number into a new column in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have existing script that does a major chunk of what I need. The script (from here: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4054-excel-duplicate-rows-based-on-cell-value.html) basically inserts and then copies rows of data X number of times, where X is one of the fields in the table. It works well and the referenced page shows examples of the start and end points.

But when I run the script in Excel I go from ~2,000 lines in my table to ~40,000 lines. I need to modify all the duplicated rows (incremental dates) and so I am now attemting to also include new data into the table while the script runs that will allow me to change data in the duplicated rows... for example I can use the duplicate number 1, 2, 3, 4 and some simple formulas to change dates relative to a start point.

I expect that I will need some additional code inserted into the routine that will add data into a nominated column and do the auto incrementing from 1.

Having zero actual VBA skillz, ive no idea how to tackle the second part of my problem with the code I already have. Any help would be totally awesome !!

```
Sub CopyData()
'Updateby Extendoffice 20160922
    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim VInSertNum As Variant
    xRow = 1
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While (Cells(xRow, "A") <> "")
        VInSertNum = Cells(xRow, "D")
        If ((VInSertNum > 1) And IsNumeric(VInSertNum)) Then
           Range(Cells(xRow, "A"), Cells(xRow, "D")).Copy
           Range(Cells(xRow + 1, "A"), Cells(xRow + VInSertNum - 1, "D")).Select
           Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
           xRow = xRow + VInSertNum - 1
        End If
        xRow = xRow + 1
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried thusfar?  Having zero skill currently, and asking others to do it for you, isn't really what StackOverflow is about.  You can build your skill-set!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code below, I used the same sample data on the link you provided. However on this code I created 2 worksheets, one for the raw data to be processed and one for the duplicate output including the increment of dates and duplicate number.

```
Sub duplicateData()

Dim rSH As Worksheet
Set rSH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RAW") 'Your raw data
Dim oSH As Worksheet
Set oSH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OUTPUT") 'Output data on another sheet

x = 2
For a = 2 To rSH.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For b = 1 To rSH.Cells(a, 4).Value '4 is the column of duplicate times
        If b = 1 Then
            For c = 1 To 4 'Number of your column
                oSH.Cells(x, c).Value = rSH.Cells(a, c).Value
            Next c
            oSH.Cells(x, 5) = 1 'First instance, 5 is the column number of duplicate counter
        Else
            For c = 1 To 4 'Number of your column
                oSH.Cells(x, c).Value = rSH.Cells(a, c).Value
            Next c
            oSH.Cells(x, 3).Value = CDate(oSH.Cells(x - 1, 3).Value) + 1 '3 is the column number of date to increment
            oSH.Cells(x, 5).Value = CInt(oSH.Cells(x - 1, 5).Value) + 1 '5 is the column number of duplicate counter
        End If
        x = x + 1 'Increment Output row number
    Next b
Next a
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey there Love Coding. Thank you. This works exactly how I wanted and lets me achieve the outcome. Sincerely appreaciate your time here, and this example is a great way for me to learn.